# NServiceBus IBus object

Tags: .net, nservicebus

I believe I've made a foolish assumption that the IBus object will be loaded throughout an application and it's referenced assemblies.

For instance if I was to do the following inside of a referenced assembly:

```
public IBus Bus {get;set;}
```

Am I correct in saying that this object will only be loaded on classes that implement an NServiceBus class such as IHandleMessages and IWantToBeLoadedAtStartup?

Any help or clarification on the specifics would be great.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you're referring to is Dependency Injection. NServiceBus will inject an `IBus` instance only into objects which are managed by NServiceBus.

For example, NServiceBus creates an instance of classes implementing `IHandleMessages` when a transport message arrives and injects an instance of the bus client using the Dependency Injection container.

You can extend the dependency injection mechanism as shown [here](http://docs.particular.net/nservicebus/containers).

Comment: Yup you've confirmed my worst suspicion unfortunately. Basically, I've created an error reporting application that requires access to the Bus object throughout the 'business logic' of my application however to do this I need access to the bus object through many different classes. ( I realise I should throw exceptions rather than report, It's a plagued system that's slowly being revamped ) Am I potentially asking the wrong question in this case?

Comment: You may register an instance of IBus in your own dependency container such that it injects it into classes depending on it, or pass it around starting from where you configure it or from a place where the instance gets injected automatically. Also, I would try to limit the exposure of NSB interfaces throughout your application. Instead, use NSB as an adapter to messaging infrastructure and have all message handlers delegate to application services.

Comment: I'm wondering how you resolved this problem? I'm struggling with the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you use another container instead of the default one the container will have automatically wired bus IBus instance which is provided by NSB container abstraction. There is no need to register it elsewhere. It can be injected anywhere.